# Why are both players doing the animation when only one should?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to build this basic multiplayer game, it's sort of a mmorpg game.
This is how it works so far..
When I connect to the game, I can see my character walking around just fine, but when my friend connects and stands still and I walk around, I can see my character walking and doing the walk animation, but so is his character, and his character also moves even tho he is standing still on his computer.

This is the setup.. When I walk (Press W) the client sends the input to the server, and then the server sends back a packet to the client which then updates the players position, this is also where I'm trying to update the players animation.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Packet that's received when the server updates the players position.
    /// This happens every game tick, even if the player is standing still
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_packet"></param>
    public static void PlayerPosition(Packet _packet)
    {
        //The players id
        int _id = _packet.ReadInt();
        //The players position
        Vector3 position = _packet.ReadVector2();
        //GameManager.players[_id].transform.position = position;


        //var clientAnimator = GameManager.players[_id].GetComponent<Animator>();
        if (position != GameManager.players[_id].position)
        {
            GameManager.players[_id].GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("isWalking", true);
            GameManager.players[_id].position = position;
        }
        else
        {
            GameManager.players[_id].GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("isWalking", false);
        }
    }
```

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong that is super obvious?

Answer (score 1):

To the **why**:

I bet your player is a prefab so both player instances have an `Animator` component in which **one and the same** `AnimatorController` is referenced.

As a result setting a Bool or changing to any State in it affects both players' `Animator`. Since this is not synchronized it happens only on your side but for both players simultaneously.

---

I don't know if this is possible in an easy way on runtime but a fix for this would probably consist in creating a new individual `AnimatorController` instance (clone) for each player instance.

Maybe it would be possible to simply clone the [`Animator.RuntimeAnimatorController`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeAnimatorController.html) something like

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class AnimatorSetup : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Reference this via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private Animator _animator;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // As fallback get it on runtime
        if(!_animator) _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

        // Clonet he currently reference animator controller
        var newController = Instantiate(_animator.runtimeAnimatorController);
        // Use the new instance of the controller for this animator
        _animator.runtimeAnimatorController = newController;
    }
}
```

and put this on the player prefab next to the `Animator` component.

Comment: I should of made that clear, I have two player prefabs one localPlayer and one Player, both have a animator controller :-)

Comment: @RileyVarga so both have completely different controllers? Did you try debugging then and check how often your `PlayerPosition` is called and with which ID's? E.g. for starters simply do `Debug.Log($"Packet Received for Id={_id }");` and also `Debug.Log(GameManager.players[_id].name)` in the `if` block and check if it prints only your players name